# Character encoding of GET request parameter

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, encoding, utf-8

Hello fellow Stackoverflowers.

I have an issue that i need some help with:

We're making an http GET web service call from a smartphone app to a Java/Spring MVC application. We're on a Tomcat application server that is fronted by an Apache server with a mod_proxy proxy setup.

One of the parameters imbedded in the URL is the word "Männen", which is the organization name that's one of the parameters. The app makes a Jquery Ajax GET request and the parameter leaves the app as "M%E4nnen", which to my understanding means the "ä" has been properly URL-encoded. When it arrives to the Spring controller, it has been distorted to "MÃ¤nnen".

I have googled and found quite a few threads on this and they all recommend modifying the Tomcat server.xml file by adding URIEncoding="UTF-8" to all connectors. Of course, i tried this. It made a change but did not solve the issue. The string now comes through as "Mï¿½nnen". There was also a thread suggesting you add "nocanon" to the ProxyPass parameter in the Apache proxy configuration. This was tried but made no difference.

Using the logs, i can follow the request:

1. In the Apache access log, the parameter is logged as "M%E4nnen"
2. In the Apache proxy log, the parameter is logged as "M%E4nnen"
3. In the Tomcat localhost_access log, the parameter is logged as "M%E4nnen"
4. In the Spring controller that receives the request, the parameter is logged as "Mï¿½nnen"

My Spring application also has a character encoding filter, but as far as i understand, it only works on the request body. It is configured as shown below:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
  </init-param>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I really don't know what else to try or where else to look. If anyone could guide me in the right direction, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a question open for more than 7 years. It seems the json request is made under the assumption that the server is ISO-8859-1 (GET with "M%E4nnen") - not so nice. Then somehow it converted to UTF-8, but interpreted as ISO-8859-1 (two bytes). Not nice; a case of go back to start.

Comment: Yeah, it's about time we close this one. Unfortunately, i can't really remember how we sorted it out. A few more character encoding problems have passed over the years and i haven't enjoyed a single one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML is in Windows-1252 (or the "subset" ISO-8859-1), then %E4 is okay.
If however the HTML is in Unicode, UTF-8, then not.

```
String auml = "\u00e4";
String aumlPerc = URLEncoder(auml, "UTF-8");
URLDecoder.decode(aumlPerc, "UTF-8");
```

Besides the HTML page having charset UTF-8, you can have `<form accept-charset="UTF-8" ...>`.

It seems the page erroneously sends %E4, is accepted as ISO-8859-1 (the default), converted to a multi-byte UTF-8 sequence, but that then is wrongly considered to be ISO-8859-1.

There are some screws to set the encoding, like `request.setEncoding`, but with the limited information I cannot say where to look. Maybe this information suffices.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Let me clarify. This is a RESTful web service. There is no HTML involved. The service sends a GET request (a URL containing the request parameters) which is processed by the service and returned as an XML structure.

Comment: Then init param `encoding` should probably be `ISO-8859-1` the HTTP default.

Comment: Init param of what - Tomcat or Apache? It sounds strange to me to use ISO-8859-1 when we're trying to achieve a process that's all UTF-8.

Comment: TomCat, the web.xml above. Yes it is somewhat strange, but a byte %E4, for ä, U+00E4, is definitely not UTF-8. Further on there is a conversion ISO-8859-1-to-UTF-8 too, resulting in several chars, what should have been several bytes + UTF-8 encoding. Give it a try.

Comment: Joop, please help me out here. My web.xml has only one place where encoding is set and that's the very first line: That's not what you mean, is it? `code`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

Comment: My fault, I meant CharacterEncodingFilter, above, mixed things up.

Comment: OK; this is getting interesting My application's web.xml has a CharacterEncodingFilter, which is configured like this: `<filter>
  <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
  </init-param>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>`

Comment: Tomcat also has a web.xml that contains a SetCharacterEncodingFilter, but it's commented out.

Comment: But doesn't a CharacterEncodingFilter only work on information inside the request and not request parameters?

Comment: It is the declarative way of calling `request.setEncoding`. I use it for the request parameters, and always check GET and POST fpr special chars- Did ypu substitute UTF-8 by ISO-8859-1 once for a try?